# C# Split byte[] by hexademimal value into new array of byte[]

Tags: c#, mpeg2-ts

I want to take data from an IP packet which is a byte array and split it into a collection of byte arrays that start with `0x47` i.e. [mpeg-2 transport packets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream)

For example the original byte array looks like this:

```
08 FF FF 47 FF FF FF 47 FF FF 47 FF 47 FF FF FF FF 47 FF FF
```

How would you split the byte array on `0x47` and retain the deliminator `0x47` so it looks like this? In order words an array of byte arrays that start on a particular hexadecimal?

```
[0] 08 FF FF
[1] 47 FF FF FF
[2] 47 FF FF
[3] 47 FF
[4] 47 FF FF FF FF
[5] 47 FF FF
```

Comment: Why not simply loop through that? That ought to work in like O(2n) time, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily implement the splitter required:

```
public static IEnumerable<Byte[]> SplitByteArray(IEnumerable<Byte> source, byte marker) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

  List<byte> current = new List<byte>();

  foreach (byte b in source) {
    if (b == marker) {
      if (current.Count > 0)
        yield return current.ToArray();

      current.Clear();
    }

    current.Add(b);
  }

  if (current.Count > 0)
    yield return current.ToArray();
}
```

and use it:

```
  String source = "08 FF FF 47 FF FF FF 47 FF FF 47 FF 47 FF FF FF FF 47 FF FF";

  // the data
  Byte[] data = source
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
    .ToArray();

  // splitted
  Byte[][] result = SplitByteArray(data, 0x47).ToArray();

  // data splitted has been represented for testing
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    result.Select(line => String.Join(" ", line.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))));

  // 08 FF FF
  // 47 FF FF FF
  // 47 FF FF
  // 47 FF
  // 47 FF FF FF FF
  // 47 FF FF
  Console.Write(report);
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
byte[] source = // ...
string packet = String.Join(" ", source.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));

// chunks is of type IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>>
var chunks = Regex.Split(packet, @"(?=47)")
             .Select(c =>
                 c.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little too hacky for you, but should work just fine:

```
string ins = "08 FF FF 47 FF FF FF 47 FF FF 47 FF 47 FF FF FF FF 47 FF FF ";
string[] splits = ins.Split(new string[] { "47" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++) {
     splits[i] = "47 " + splits[i];
}
```

Edit: similar to the already existing answer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this, the easiest approach is to just use .Split() and replace the value that is being split on.

```
string[] values = packet.Split("47");
for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] 47 {1}", i, values[i]);
    // C# 6+ way: Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] 47 {values[i]}");
}
```

Of course, you can always use regular expressions, but my Regex skills are pretty limited and I don't think I could personally construct a valid regex for this.

Comment: This would work, `string[] mpegPackets = Regex.Split(data, "(?=47)");` I guess you are right I need to convert the hex values to string in order to split.

Comment: Isn't the question about an Array of `byte`s?