# How to split a byte array by a particular array value in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

How to split a byte array by a particular array value in c#?

```
    byte[] largeBytes = [70,68,49,59,117,49,59,112];
```

I just want to split the array bye "59" so that I can get 3 byte arrays.
I have tried a lot ,couldn't find the solution.  thanks in advance

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020581/c-sharp-split-byte-by-hexademimal-value-into-new-array-of-byte/38020807. The same way can apply to decimal values using a marker.

Comment: you  want to include 59  byte or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the algorithm on how you can achieve this

```
 //Here I'm not including 59 in the sub arrays  
       var largeBytes = new byte[] {70,68,49,59,117,49,59,112};
        var lists = new List<List<byte>>();
        const int marker = 59;
        var tempLst = new List<byte>();
        foreach (var largeByte in largeBytes)
        {


            if (largeByte==marker)
            {
                lists.Add(tempLst);               
                tempLst=new List<byte>();
            }
            else
            {
                tempLst.Add(largeByte);    
            }

        }
        lists.Add(tempLst);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use the [Split](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Split.cs#L35) extension method from [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) :

```
byte separator=59;
var triplets=largeBytes.Split(separator);
```

This will return an IEnumerable of `IEnumerable<byte>`. You can convert it to an `IEnumerable<byte[]>` with `ToArray()`:

```
var triplets=largeBytes.Split(separator).Select(triplet=>triplet.ToArray());
```

Or you can do roughly what the extension method does - create an iterator that checks each input element until it finds the separator and places each character in an array:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T separator)
{
    List<T> result=new List<T>(3);
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if (item == separator)
        {
            yield return result;
            result=new List<T>(3);
        }
        else 
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return result;
}
```

You can use this extension method in the same way:

```
byte separator=59;
var triplets=largeBytes.Split(separator);
```

or

```
var triplets=MyExtensionsClass.Split(largeBytes,separator);
```

MoreLINQ's version is a lot more versatile, as it allows you to specify a maximum number of splits, or transform the input into another form

If you want to *include* the separator, you put `result.Add` before the first `if`. A better option would be to add an `include` parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T separator,bool include=false)
{
    List<T> result=new List<T>(3);
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if (item == separator)
        {
            if (include) result.Add(item);
            yield return result;
            result=new List<T>(3);
        }
        else 
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.IndexOf(largeBytes, (byte)59, index)` where index will be last found index (0 in beginning) in loop, until function returns `-1` (no more `59` found in array). 
On boundaries created by `(byte)59`, copy some sub-array as is written in this answer: [Getting a sub-array from an existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943635/getting-a-sub-array-from-an-existing-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could use IEnumerable's `GroupBy` to perform the split:

```
byte[] largeBytes = new byte[] {70,68,49,59,117,49,59,112};
byte split = 59;
long index = 0;
var results = largeBytes.GroupBy(b => index += Convert.ToInt64(b==split)); 
foreach (var result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Group Key: {result.Key}");
    foreach (var value in result) {
        Console.WriteLine($" - Value: {value}");
    }
}
```

Just for fun, here's a way to do it using C#7's Tuples:

```
byte[] largeBytes = new byte[] {70,68,49,59,117,49,59,112};
byte split = 59;
long index = 0;
var results = largeBytes.Select(x => ((index += Convert.ToInt64(x == 59)),x));
foreach (var tuple in results) { 
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Item1}: {tuple.Item2}");
}
```

Demo: http://csharppad.com/gist/079cc46095bb938f716587693d7ea8af